# Using ngView Makes Any Process Twice

Tags: angularjs, ng-view, angularjs-ng-route

When I use `ngView` and call a controller inside another one, this makes any process twice :

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/main.html',
        controller: 'main'
    })
    .when('/user', {
        templateUrl: '/user.html',
        controller: 'user'
    })
    });

<body ng-controller="main">
     <div ng-view><!--here is another controller --></div>
</body>
```

[image]
[image]

When using `ngInclude` there is not this problem. What is wrong with using `ngView`?

Comment: please share some code

Comment: What are you using ngView for exactly... Show us code

Comment: @Dsafds I have edited my question

Comment: What Angular.JS Version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like if you are using your `main` controller twice:

- By referencing it in the template as ng-controller
- In the routing config of the "/" route

Probably you want remove the `ng-controller` from your index page?